# Mesh is transparent when imported

Tags: mesh, transparency

I've created a model in Fuse and exported it as an OBJ with all the maps included. But when the model is imported into Blender, the mesh is see-through. You can see the eyeballs and teeth without clipping into the mesh and in general textures look translucent.

The mesh has glasses, which I've assigned to be the only part transparent, but despite that, the mesh still looks transparent. I've checked the opacity map and the only white part are the glasses.

What should I do to fix this?

Here's how it looks:
[image]

Comment: look at the material properties  > settings. the blend and shadow mode should be Opaque, when importing OBJ with materials it is often set to transluent.

Comment: It was set to opaque already, however the "Show backface" box was on, and when I turned it off, the transparency disappeared! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by going into the *Material Settings* menu after selecting the character (Sphere icon with red and black patches). Then, I went to the *Settings* tab under the *Material Menu* and unchecked the box that said *Show Backface*.

Answer (score 1):

To fix that problem, go into the *Material Settings* and check if the *Blend Mode* is on *Alpha Blend*. If it is then switch it to *Opaque*.

Answer (score -1):

What happened with mine was the the *Backface* setting was enabled. If you go to the *Material Settings*, then scroll down to the *Show Backface* option. On each image texture, diable it (except the ones you want to keep transparent).

Comment: That's indeed the problem, but that's not at all the solution. Flip the normals, don't just compensate for them.