# The faces of my model.blend are invisible

Tags: texturing, uv, .fbx

The faces of my.blend model are transparent, rather invisible ?, I am struggling with this for several days and I hope that there is a solution, I will leave an image below where I will select a face and other problems that may be affecting.
[image]

I deleted something, some folders of mine with some textures, which are also in other folders which is as if I had not completely deleted them, maybe that affected, my file was fine before that, I opened my file and this problem appeared. Then I take everything out of the recycle bin,but the problem persists.

[image]

Another thing I downloaded Wondershare Recuba to find a file, the address file that blender gives me when I put find missing textures (loca bea .... 4.2.fbm - it is rare that it was saved as fbm when it was fbx, no I can't even find it in Recuba).

Perhaps that is also the problem, is that all my files that by the way I keep several copies are the same, some worse than others.

When I open one of my copies or the original, a loading bar appears at the bottom that says loading shading or something.
[image]
I tried using mesh / normals / flip, but nothing. Thank you for reading - i don´t speak english, i used google translator

This is opaque? o where [image]

An update of my problem:
I decided to install a new version of blender, version 2.82, it did not solve anything, but when I started using it there were some different things and I decided to use the old version 2.81 (a different version 2.81 than the one I had, it was 2.81 and something, but it was older), I installed it and when I opened my file everything was fine, I was happy, I used blender for more than two hours, I was modifying my file that I had recovered, but suddenly blender closed and my screen blinked (something fast) and it appeared a box at the bottom right on the desktop, said there was a problem with the screen but it was already solved, when I opened blender it said that "OpenLg3" or something like that is missing, that box had already appeared with the first blender, so that I solved that problem with this version of blender and copied that extension and pasted it where it should have been. I opened my blender and again this problem. I add this because it may be useful information.

Comment: Where? I posted a photo

Comment: Hey :). This could help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/177064/

Comment: That does not happen with me, if you realize their faces are transparent and mine are invisible. Yes, I will change the title right now.