# Blender character material becomes transparent when exported to GLTF

Tags: modeling, animation, gltf

My character in Blender looks good with material but When I export it to GLTF format the material becomes transparent. I am not sure as whats happening. How can I fix this ? Please see the below images.

**MyCharacter in Blender:**

[image]

**Character when exported to gltf format (as seen in gltf viewer):**

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Answer (score 1):

In Blender select the character then *Material Properties > Settings*. If the *Blend Mode* is on *Alpha Blend* change it to *Opaque* and now export it to GLTF format.

The exported file will not have the transparent material issue.

Got the answer from [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/240953/162874)

Answer (score 0):

If your model faces is red, then you need to reverse the normal direction
[image: mesh face noraml is true?]

[image: reverse normal dir]